# chrome and safari flex height 100% failure

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Chrome is normal，Safari failure。How can that be compatible? `height:100%;`

I need to keep Chrome and use Safari. My Safari version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

* ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.d {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a recent Safari rendering bug involving `flex-direction: column`. You're putting two `height: 100%` elements into the same space, and they're both rendering at 100% height and stacking instead of fitting into the same space.

Here are two solutions:

1. Change `height: 100%` to `height: 50%` so both elements are half the height of their parent, or...
2. Remove the `height` attribute and add `flex: 1` so both children grow as large as they can in the parent's space, and split themselves 50/50 automatically.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.d {
  height: 50%;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.d {
  flex: 1;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

Comment: @user8478616 I misunderstood the issue until you pointed out that you were on a new version of Safari, not a legacy one.

Comment: He can also use flex-basis: 100%; or height: 50%; to solve. But he does not meet my requirements. Telescopic box default flex-shrink: 1; did not play a role.